# ServiceStack not using custom converter for NodaTime.Instant

Tags: c#, sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

In an effort to improve performance, I recently added some denormalized SQL views to our database and created some query models that correlate. Everything is working great except for one thing -- ServiceStack Ormlite isn't using my custom type converter for some of the query model fields and I can't figure out why. What's really confusing is that it *is* using the converter for the model that correlates to an actual table.

I've confirmed that the field names correlate to columns being returned by the database. I've confirmed that the SQL query Ormlite is constructing includes the fields in question. I've confirmed that the data being returned from that SQL is valid. But for some reason Ormlite never hits the `FromDbValue` method in my converter.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing:

**Write Model**

```
public class Session
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Instant SessionTime { get; set; } // <-- this is populated properly

    // -- other fields --

    [References(typeof(User))]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Reference]
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

**Query Model**

```
public class SessionQueryModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Instant SessionTime { get; set; } // <-- this IS NOT populated

    // -- other fields --

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
}
```

The write model correlates to a table named `Session`. The query model correlates to a view called `SessionQueryModel` that already has the `User` table joined in and retrieves the name fields.

My `Instant` data is stored in a `DATETIME2` field, and I register my custom converter properly. If anything were wrong there, the write model wouldn't successfully be hydrated.

I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on. I can't see any difference between the two, the field names match up, etc. The only thing I can figure is that Ormlite for some reason can't glean the type from a view in the same way it can from a table. Any ideas what might be causing this?

**UPDATE**
It appears that it's not just my `Instant` fields. There are a handful of other fields that aren't being populated as well, even though they're in the data with names matching the properties in the query model POCO. There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason. Some of these are simple `VARCHAR` columns mapping to string properties.

Now I'm really confused.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The class in question had two `enum` properties. One was of type `SessionStates` and the other `SessionStatuses`. I guess I didn't pay attention to the Intellisense entry originally, and the similar names made it not so easy to see.

Anyway, the `enum` values are stored in SQL as strings, not integers, and when ServiceStack was mapping, I can only assume the inability to parse the string to an `enum` value caused all mapping to cease.

Demis, if you're out there, this looks like it's probably a bug. I would think the system should throw an error if there was a parsing error as opposed to simply stopping mapping.